# How to split an array in half and swap the second parts of elements with first part of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

Possibly with loop for in javascript and not methods

here my specs for the exercise :

Write a function called `Swapper()`
that takes in input as a parameter an array
and, after exchanging the first and second halves, return to the caller the modified array.
Example

```
input: [5, 11, 1, 44, 2, 43]
output: [44, 2, 43, 5, 11, 1]
```

If the array has odd length, the center value must remain unchanged in place.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and give us a proper explanation of what the problem with that was, resp. what part of this you weren't able to achieve on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out

```js
const sample = [5, 11, 1, 44, 43, 46];
var split=0, arr, arr1, arr2;

if(sample.length%2==0) split = sample.length / 2;
else split = (sample.length - 1)/2;

arr1 = sample.slice(0,split);
if(sample.length%2==0){
   arr2 = sample.slice(split, sample.length);
   arr = [arr2,arr1];
}
else{
   arr2 = sample.slice(split+1, sample.length);
   arr = [arr2,sample[split],arr1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use array.splice method to split an array in half and store the result in a temporary variavble and than use spread operator to combine both the arrays into a single one.
    
    let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    let temp = a.splice(0,a.length/2);
    let splitted = [...a , ...temp];
    console.log(splitted)
```